# C# Retrive information from dozen of text files

Tags: c#

Hope someone will be able to help me.

I have a folder where I saved some text files. All text files are similar. They look like this:

> 12 Milk 33 18/20/2020
>   15 Fruit 44 18/20/2019

And let's say this is second

> 10 Coca_Cola 4 1/2/2019
>   15 Fruit 5 18/20/2020

So first comes ID, Name, Count and date at the end. So I'm looping through all text files, and I want to know what's the product with highest count on storage for example. All text files are similar, but it doesn't mean they all have same products.

In this case, my program should say - `15 Fruit 49`

Example code:

```
string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path); 
int count = 0; 

foreach(var line in allFiles) 
{ 
    List<string> oneFile = new List<string(); 
    oneFile.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(line)); 

    foreach(var oneLine in oneFile) 
    { 
        string[] justOneLine = oneLine.Split(" "); 
        count+= int.Parse(justOneLine[2]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far in order to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question contains some good details, sample input, and expected output which is great. However, you are lacking a clear question of what you are stuck on. Also, please _edit_ your question to provide any code you have written so far.

Comment: How are you splitting each line into fields? Are you storing the data before processing or processing 'on the fly'?

Comment: string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);
              int count = 0;
              foreach(var line in allFiles)
              {
              List<string> oneFile = new List<string();
              oneFile.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(line));
              foreach(var oneLine in oneFile)
              {
              string[] justOneLine = oneLine.Split(" ");
              count+= int.Parse(justOneLine[2]);
              }
              }

Comment: This code is mistake, that's for sure. This way I will count number of all products..
But I dont know how to get product that has highest count in all files.

Comment: Are you sure about your files names? How did you manage to include `/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outline solution, not tested. There are more compact ways to do this but I've tried to show each step.

Create a class to hold a line

```
public class StockItem
{
    public string StockName { get; set; }
    public int StockCount { get; set; }
}
```

You can then add all the stock items to a list.

```
List<StockItem> allItems = new List<StockItem>();
string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path); 
foreach(var file in allFiles)
{
    // open the file - you need to read the file here - and create thisFile
    foreach(string line in thisFile)
    {
        string[] thisItem = line.Split(' ');
        allItems.Add(new StockItem() {StockName = thisItem[1], StockCount = int.Parse(thisItem[2])});
    }

}
```

Run a `linq` query to get the sum of each item.

```
Dictionary<string, int> itemCounts = allItems.GroupBy(i => i.StockName)
                                    .Select(m => new
                                    {
                                        Name = m.First().StockName,
                                        Total = m.Sum(x => x.StockCount)
                                    }).ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Total);
```

This creates a dictionary of the item name with its total stock count.

And finally, query the dictionary to find its maximum stock count and all items which have this value.

```
int maxValue = itemCounts.Max(x => x.Value);
List<string> itemsWithMaxValue = itemCounts.Where(x => x.Value == maxValue)
                                           .Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello Peter. I tried to implement your code, but I got an error. Says something like
 initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

Sorry , I'm new to all this :)

Comment: Peter. I tried to put all the lines from all the text file into new text file. And  I managed to do it. ( Later after the program finishes I'm gonna delete it with System.IO.File.Delete(path);

But here is the problem now, I looped through all of the lines, and managed to count all products. But, they are repeating now. For example I get something like this.

Value of Fruit in all files is 50 ( and this will repeat as many times as Fruit accours in line. ) Do you know how to bypass this? :)

Comment: @Tomo My initial solution was incomplete and had errors. I've now updated this so, apart from the code to read the files, this should now give the required results.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!